# removing row with specific data-r

Tags: jquery, row

i have a simple table:

```
<table id="product-table">
    <tr data-r="12">
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-r="34">
        <td>three</td>
        <td>four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and i want to use jquery to remove the row that contains specific data-r data.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#product-table tr').attr('data-r')` will return the `data-r` value of the first selected element.

You want to *search* for an element with this attribute, which you can do with the [*attribute selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var value = 12;
$('#product-table tr[data-r="' + value + '"]').remove();
```

jQuery has very good [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). All selectors are listed [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

Using this line of code, would not work. 
Here an example :

```
$('#product-table tr[data-r=34]').remove();
```

This will remove the second line.

Answer (score 0):

It is longer, but prettier

```
$("tr").filter(function(){return $(this).data("r")==34}).remove();
```

Comment: actually the selected answer looks a lot more pretty in my eyes, since it is simple to understand.